# ng-model doesn't work along with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's all about this block:

```
<div class="panel done-{{ todo.done }}" ng-repeat="todo in todos()" ng-click="changeStatus(todo)">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done"> {{ todo.title }}
</div>
```

Removing the outer ng-click the checkbox works fine, not doing so just the ng-click will work. Ng-click will change the value of the checkbox though while the checkbox doesn't change state.

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(todo) {
  todo.done = ! todo.done;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now. This might be a bit ugly but it works:

```
<div class="panel done-{{ todo.done }}" ng-repeat="todo in todos()" ng-click="changeStatus(todo)">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" ng-click="changeStatus(todo)"> {{ todo.title }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the ng-click should go in the input field:

```
<div class="panel done-{{ todo.done }}" ng-repeat="todo in todos()" >
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" ng-click="changeStatus(todo)"/> {{ todo.title }}
</div>
```

and your function should have the ! operator attached to the variable or it will fail:

```
$scope.changeStatus = function(todo) {
  todo.done = !todo.done;
};
```

Comment: Tried the change but it doesn't work. Also it would not make much sense as I want the panel to be clickable which works fine.

Comment: "should have the ! operator attached to the variable or it will fail"
I'm coming from PHP but it works fine and should be pretty much the same, not matter how many spaces you put in there, shouldn't it?

Comment: I thought you wanted the input to change when the checkbox was clicked, not anything else, my bad. I think your problem is that checkboxes values aren't true or false, they are a string, for example, value='todo 1', and the checkbox will only be checked if the ng-model equals 'todo 1' (todo.done = 'todo 1')